# Use layout XML to create button

Tags: android, xml

I've defined a layout in XML and now I'd like to use it to make a custom button (It just has to show the layout and be clickable, I don't care about different states and stuff). I'm not too sure what to do next though. How to I create this in my main activity?

Thanks!

My custom XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/text" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/left"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:maxWidth="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/dim_foreground_material_dark"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/horiz" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting an ID to the whole layout and then reference it in your code with `findViewById()` method. Then attach an onclick event to the object.

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm having trouble with :P How can I attatch an ID to this layout and use it in my activity.xml? I've tried referencing the layout by file name, but that doesn't work

Comment: Add the android:id="@+id/layout_id" attribute to your <RelativeLayout>

Comment: Ah right -_- Now I'd be able to use that in java, but I want to use in it XML in the main activity. Using the file name or the ID doesn't work as a tag name :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start by exploring how we can create custom view:

1)Subclass one of the built-in layouts.

2)Inflate a merge layout in the constructor.

3)Initialize members to point to inner views with findViewById().

4)Add your own APIs to query and update the view state.

So I think you want to use the second option:

```
public class ButtonView extends Button  {

    public ButtonView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ButtonView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_xml, this, true);

    }


}
```

for further reading take a look at:

[Custom Layouts on Android](http://lucasr.org/2014/05/12/custom-layouts-on-android/)

Comment: Are there any functional differences between your solution and mine?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. you can do a lot of stuff in java class for example at `onDraw` method or you can do anything you like. It is very flexible. But if your requirement dose not need that  flexibility use your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I can reference the layout in XML by using an `<include/>` tag.

```
<include layout="@layout/settings_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/accountStaticUnderline"
    android:id="@+id/termBegin"/>
```